# Handle scrolling of a huge Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, scroll

**I'm in stuck with my layout with a lot of recyclerViews (4).**

If three recyclers have up to 20 items per each and they are `GONE` by default in xml, then fourth recycler has up to 100-400 items (not more) which are dynamically changing in code and it is `VISIBLE` by default.

I **need** to scroll (smoothly scroll, ofc) all of menu (layout) including all of it elements.

I was trying `NestedScrollView`, `ScrollView` for all layout, for pieces of layout, for recyclerViews.

I was trying this for `RecyclerView`: `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`

I was trying:

```
layoutManager.setAutoMeasureEnabled(true); //deprecated
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

I was trying `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` for Nested

I was trying `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"` for `RecyclerView`

I was trying `adapter.setHasStableIds(true);`

I was trying to combine all of this things from stackoverflow and other resources.

I have achieved scrolling which I want just by simple adding `NestedScrollView` after my `rootLayout` (not smooth, but works correct), but only in AVD, real devices with up to 3GB RAM cannot handle adding of `NestedScrollView` - devices are getting infinite black screen and empty Logs.

**Maybe I was trying to do something else and I've forgotten to type about them here. Comment about some another similar fixes and I will reply.**

How I can achieve smooth scrolling all of `rootLayout` elements?

*I know that rule about scrolling views inside of another scrolling views, but I **need** to scroll all of my scrollable recyclers.*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
    android:background="@color/float_transparent">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LLMenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/gray21"

        >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/RLTop"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

            <View
                android:id="@+id/BluecolorView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@color/colorBlue"
                >
            </View>
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:layout_below="@+id/BluecolorView"
                >
            </View>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/FLIV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/logoinmenu"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
                android:src="@drawable/logoicon"

                >
            </ImageView>
        </FrameLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TVUserName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textViewTextSize"
            android:text=""
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"

        >
        </TextView>



        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LLAllM"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible"
            >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LL"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/LLIVandBTG"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:visibility="visible"
                >

                <ImageView />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/BTGenresRV"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:background="@color/float_transparent"
                    android:text="@string/genres"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:gravity="start|top"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    >

                </Button>


            </LinearLayout>

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/RVGenresList"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

                >
            </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>


        </LinearLayout>


        Here are three more similar to "<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LL" blocks...



        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

**UPD:**

I've forgotten to add that all of this handling by a `public class MenuFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnTouchListener`

Fragment are located in `ActivityName extends AppCompatActivity`

**UPD2:**

Partially fixed it by adding `ScrollView` after `rootLayout` and static height to recyclers.

**Will see, maybe this is the best solution and I will provide full code in answer.**

**UPD3:** This is because of `wrap_content` and `match_parent` I was not able to scroll like I need.